# How to make a bound data member a default value in WPF ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an `ObservableCollection<string>` named `MyCollection` containing `"A", "B", "C", "D"`. I create a view like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" 
    SelectedIndex="{Binding 3}"/>
<Button Click="OnClickButton">Button</Button>
```

Then my codebehind looks like this:

```
public partial class MyClass {
    private string _mySelection;

    public string MySelection 
    {
        get { return _mySelection; }
        set 
        {
            _mySelection = value;
        }
    }

    public void OnClickButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MySelection = (MyComboBox.SelectedItem).ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(MySelection);
    }
```

This is fine. The ComboBox populates just as it should, and `MySelection` is set properly and appears in the message box. But currently, my ComboBox appears blank in the user interface until the user clicks on it and selects an option. I want option C to be the default value, and if the user doesn't select anything, then `MySelection` will be set to `C`.

But no matter how many **different** combinations of `SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, and `SelectedIndex` I try, I **can't** get it to work. The ComboBox always starts off **empty**.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the code where you actually set `MySelection` to something.

Comment: I'm confused. The second-to-last line doesn't count? Can you clarify?

Comment: @ribs2spare: Try `private string _mySelection = "C";`

Comment: How did you think the computer was going to magically pick the 3rd item by default in the list? Without telling it first?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I did mistype my XAML. I'll edit it for posterity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a default value of the `_mySelection` field, i.e. `"C"`

Or, more general, set the value of `MySelection` to the desired default value after construction.

Also make sure that the `MySelection` property fires a change notification.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private string mySelection;

    public string MySelection
    {
        get { return mySelection; }
        set
        {
            mySelection = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MySelection)));
        }
    }
}
```

Initialize the DataContext of the view with an instance of `MyViewModel`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var vm = new MyViewModel();
    vm.MyCollection.Add("A");
    vm.MyCollection.Add("B");
    vm.MyCollection.Add("C");
    vm.MyCollection.Add("D");
    vm.MySelection = "C";
    DataContext = vm;
}

private void OnClickButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((MyViewModel)DataContext).MySelection);
}
```

Comment: Yes!!!! This worked! It's strange because I recall seeing similar answers elsewhere on the net, but something about this must be different because this is the only method that worked. Thank you SO much. I've been struggling with this for far longer than I'd like to admit.

Comment: @ribs2spare no, that’s exactly how it is done.  There is nothing unique about this answer.  +1